# Grails tests - run code before/after full test phase

Tags: grails, spock

Is there a way to run some code before/after an entire test phase in Grails?  For example, if I run `grails test-app unit:` I'd like to run some code the unit test phase, and after all unit tests run, run another piece of code.  This is different than what `beforeSpec` and `afterSpec` are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you can do is to use the events system provided by grails. You can edit _Events.groovy with the hook methods provided by grails:

- TestPhaseStart
- TestCaseStart
- TestStart
- TestEnd
- TestCaseEnd
- TestPhaseEnd

More information can be found at this [article](https://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/grails-custom-clean-up-during-testing-using-build-events/) as well as the [grails docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/commandLine.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for `TestPhaseStart` and `TestPhaseEnd` specifically.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use Geb `Browser.drive` in that event handler - it looks like it hasn't read the config yet.